# ValueError at /polls/add/ The view polls.views.addQuestion didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass data from html template to django addQuestion view in my polls app.I want to make an add quetion along their vote options template and
I am using django==3.2
Here my html code

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:add' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="your_queston">Question: </label>
    <input id="question" type="text">
    <br>
    <label for="choices">Choice 1</label>
    <input id="choice1" type="text"><br>
    <label for="choices">Choice 2</label>
    <input id="choice2" type="text">
    <br>
    <label for="choices">Choice 3</label>
    <input id="choice3" type="text">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

and here my addQuestion function in view.py

```
def addQuestion(request):
    if(request.POST):
        try:
            if(request.POST['question']):
                qtext = request.POST.get('question')
                q = Question(question_text=qtext, pub_date=timezone.now())
                q.save()
            if(request.POST['choice1']):
                q.choice_set.create(
                    choice_text=request.POST.get('choice1'), votes=0)
            if(request.POST['choice2']):
                q.choice_set.create(
                    choice_text=request.POST.get('choice2'), votes=0)
            if(request.POST['choice3']):
                q.choice_set.create(
                    choice_text=request.POST.get('choice3'), votes=0)
            q.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:index'))

        except:
            pass
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/addQuestion.html')
```

Comment: Errors should never pass silently,  put some log  or print statement(for development only) instead of 'pass' and identify the error.

Comment: Never, ever use `try: except:`. Even less use `try: except: pass`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have a try-except. As mentioned in the comments, always be specific in what type of expection you want to catch.
But in your code, if an exception happens, the function returns nothing, also know as None. A better way would be:

```
def view(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      error = False
      try:
         pass # Do magic here
      except YourExpectedException:
         # Log the exception
         error = True
      if error:
         return render(request, 'polls/errorPage.html'
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:index'))

   else:
      return render(request, 'polls/addQuestion.html')
```